# How can i get the user id value from a given record

Tags: python, odoo

I need to re-create a record. I'm able to fetch out all the fields from the record but having a hard time while fetching the user id which belongs to res.user

I have a scheduled action which goes through all the records and based on some condition, re-create a record. For the re-creation of record, I need to copy all the field's value. There is a field named "assigned_to" which contains values from res.user. How can I fetch its id and write it while creating the new record? I'm trying this:

```py
for duty in duties:
  if duty.x_studio_on_date_or_after_days == 'on_date':
    user_id = env['x_duties'].search([('x_studio_assigned_to', '=', duty.x_studio_assigned_to)]).id
    #user_id =39
    current_date = datetime.datetime.now().date().strftime('%d')
    if duty.x_studio_date_of_every_month_1 == current_date:
      env['x_duties'].create({'x_name': '[Automated] '+ duty.x_name ,  'x_studio_details' : duty.x_studio_details, 'x_studio_assigned_to' : user_id  , 'x_studio_reoccurred_task' : True })
```

I'm getting this error

```
Invalid value res.users(39,) in domain term ('x_studio_assigned_to', '=', res.users(39,))
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out :)

I just need to put user_id = duty.x_studio_assigned_to.id in place of user_id = duty.x_studio_assigned_to